# Unable to access Document Property with from Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am querying a database asynchronously and getting the result.

```
const games=await new Promise(res=>{Game.find({ids:id},(err,doc)=>res(doc))})
console.log(games[0])
```

When I print the result I get the following

```
{ gameId:'8636f1b196f1c6aa164341be448126ba',
  done: '1',
  score: [],
  finishedAt: '' }
```

But then when I do `console.log(games[0].done)` I get `undefined` whereas the expected output is 1

Comment: There is no JSON in your question. (And if what you've quoted were used as JSON, it would be invalid JSON.) JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Show the schema as there is likely a mismatch between the document and schema. BTW `const games = await Game.find()` works fine as mongoose methods already return a Promise.

Comment: @NeilLunn thanks, I hadnt defined it as a field in my Schema

Comment: As stated, this will be a schema mismatch. You can fix the schema or work around it with `toObject()` or adding `lean()` to the query i.e `Game.find(...).lean()`. Just note that one answer added here was a bit better at "using google" since it's just content gleaned from one of the "over involved" approaches to an answer there.